# Why is repeater post-xmit "burst" stronger than repeated signal?

Tags: repeater

I have no problem triggering GB3LW, and after I release PTT I get the strong burst from the repeater confirming that it "heard me".

But if I use two radios, the receive-only one will *only* hear that burst, with default settings, not me talking. If I hold down "monitor" on it, or set the SQL down to lowest setting, then I hear myself loud and clear.

I have also made contact over this repeater, so it should not be a matter of me having misconfigured both radios.

The baofeng UV-5RE lights up green if receiving, and activates the speaker if the tone is present. My talking doesn't light it up on the other radio (because SQL / signal strength), but the post-talking burst does.

It should therefore not be "trigger audio frequency not received, so not activating speaker".

So my question is: Why is "my talking" not being repeated as strongly enough to activate radio, but the post-talking burst is?

Comment: Check CTCSS settings for your radio. I suspect that they might be misconfigured. If you can, disable any receive CTCSS tones on the radio.

Comment: @AndrejaKo like I said:
1) It works when I reduce SQL
2) I have made contacts with this repeater, so I can receive and send.
3) The radio lights up if receving *even if* the CTCSS doesn't match.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a Baofeng, but usually, when you reduce the squelch to the lowest setting, the squelch is actually disabled. Also, some radios (perhaps your too) will allow you to have a different CTCSS for transmission and reception. In such case, if the receive CTCSS is wrong, then repeater will hear you fine, but you won't be able to hear the repeater. Also, many radios will light up, even if CTCSS doesn't match, but will not output the radio. That's why I thought that perhaps your receive CTCSS could be wrong.

Comment: For example, on my KG-UV8D, everything you describe will happen if the TX CTCSS is correct, but the RX CTCSS is wrong.

Comment: Well, I didn't set it to the lowest setting, since if I did it would "receive" and give me static the whole time.
If the RX CTCSS is wrong with KG-UV8D, then you still get the post-send burst? Huh. Well, like I also said I have made contacts over the repeater, so the RX CTCSS is at least not completely wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably experiencing what is called "desense". The strong signal of your transmitting radio is getting into the receiver on the receiving radio and blocking its ability to receive the repeater even though they are on different frequencies. As soon as you stop transmitting, the desense is gone so your receive radio can now hear the squelch tail of the repeater.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try having a friend listen from a distance to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: That was it. Simply moving away fixed it. Thank you for your correct and elaborate answer!

Comment: Glad you got it solved. Now you know why repeater hardware is so expensive...